# Where should I ask general questions about smartphones?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

[My question](https://superuser.com/questions/1632019/how-to-quickly-shield-a-smartphone-from-all-signals-wifi-cell-signal) on Super User got closed.

> Is there a way to quickly shield a smartphone from all signals? I want to replicate a real signal loss and not only go into flight mode. I tried with aluminium foil, but I still saw reception on the display. Is there a certain technique needed? Ideally someone has the tools at home and not buy special devices ...

Where do I ask general question about smartphones? In this case it is about hardware and not tied to a specific manufacturer. It is not about electronics, security, Android, iOS, Stack Overflow, etc. So is it basically it off-topic everywhere?

Comment: Kind of ridiculous at this point that SuperUser doesn't cover smartphones and web apps IMO. Different world from 2009...

Comment: @pkamb we have a different site for [webapps.se] and this isn't your typical software/hardware question. I'm not blaming [su] at all for closing this question as off-topic,

Comment: @Glorfindel WebApps is extremely low traffic compared to SO/SU and the Q/A suffers as  a result. Very little difference in asking an Excel question vs. a Google Sheets question. SE would be better for everyone if SU expanded its scope a bit IMO.

Comment: Do a search to [find the *search terms* that you need](https://www.google.com/search?q=shield%20a%20smartphone%20from%20all%20signals) to find your answer. You might find a decent [article and any caveats](https://scottiestech.info/2017/03/10/build-your-own-stylish-signal-blocking-smartphone-box-in-ten-minutes/#comment-663762). Then **come back here**  and use the main search engine to [search for your answer](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Faraday+cellphone) - you can see that the question has been asked a few times on a couple of sites.

Comment: 'I tried with aluminium foil, but I still saw reception on the display' - you have transparent aluminium?  Inside a metal cake tin in the microwave works for me.

Comment: @Rob: Yeah, I find post like [this one](https://mybroadband.co.za/news/security/246357-putting-a-smartphone-in-a-tinfoil-shoebox.html), which confirms my simple test. I believe most people don't try it yourself like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13831212/426227) ... Your second link looks promissing, but doesn't immediately fall into the category "things which you have in your household". Didn't know there is a search engine over all stackexchange sites! Thanks.

Comment: @MartinJames: No, I watched from the side ;-) If I find one, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @MartinJames: Tried it now. First, it isn't fast enough. Second, I still had Edge connection ...

Answer (score 14):

Ooh, this is a tough one. You probably need some kind of Faraday cage (while still being able to operate the phone, I presume). Here is a question on [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) where somebody tried to make one: [Homemade Faraday Cage?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/423096/113522) but I'm not familiar enough with the site to tell if they would accept your question (in its current form or perhaps if you frame it in a different way).

> Ideally someone has the tools at home and not buy special devices ...

On the other hand, that sounds more like [Lifehacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/) material. They do specialize in 'common problems' and yours seems to be quite an uncommon one...

> So basically it is off-topic everywhere?

Sadly, for some very interesting questions this is indeed the case. Fortunately, there are other sites like Quora and Reddit which may work too.